# difference between a string and alphabet symbols

Tags: definition, formal-languages

What's the difference between a string and a symbol in the alphabet for an automata? For example if you have an alphabet $\Sigma={0,1}$ Is a string a particular combination (set?) of alphabet characters that is used as input that may or may not lead to a final state?

I noticed in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) it defines a autamata as having

> a finite set of input symbols called the alphabet (Σ)

so is this just the "characters" accepted by a machine but not necessarily any particular ones that would be used as input e.g. {0,1) vs 000101

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you’ve basically got it. Symbols are the “characters” that constitute strings, which are sequences of those symbols. An automaton takes a string as an input, but its transitions and other actions that it might take are based on the symbol that it reads from the string at any point. Strings can consist of only one symbol, of course, but it’s generally clear from context whether a string or symbol is meant.